# gremlin query is too slow in DSE with large data

Tags: gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have a gremlin query to fetch a few nodes that are related to a particular node.
`g.V('123').outE().otherV().has('label','secure')`

The vertex with id 123 has at least 5000 nodes in its **outE()** with label **secure**
Also the **label** property is an indexed property for that node type in the graph schema.
This simple query takes 800ms to complete which is way too high compared to similar use cases in RDBMS.

Am I missing something here , or can someone help me optimize this more.

This is DSE 5.1.10,
Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked `.profile()` to see if the index for `label` is getting used? I suspect it is not.

Comment: Correct , index is not being used , but the field is indexed in the schema . 
Is it because of the g.V('123') ? g.V() shows use of the indexed field

Comment: what type of index is backing the label property? also, is it possible to post the  .profile() step here?

Comment: @jlacefie  So its a search index backing that property ,
And unfortunately the .profile() step's size is too big to post here , Anyway DSE graph step shows **usesIndex=false**

And Many thanks for helping out

Comment: Could the label index go on the edge as a Vertex Centric Index? That way the index would get used by the query.